# No workspace settings in VSCode json settings editor

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I created a VSCode workspace

I then saved it as `golang.code-workspace` file (say) on my `Desktop`

When double clicking the file, VSCode opens with the expected files on the explorer sidebar.

I now want to edit the particular Workspace's settings, so I hit `Command + ,` on my keyboard.

I am then presented with the following `json` file(s)

[image]

What troubles me is that according to the breadcrump (`Users > pantelis > Library > Application Support > Code > User {} settings.json`), it seems as if are some kind of global, and not workspace-specific settings.

How can I edit the settings for just the particular workspace I created?

In the UI, the distinction is more clear as you can see in the image below.

Also, in the UI, why do I get (apart from the User settings tab), 2 additional tabs (Workspace and the name of the workspace (`golang`) I just created?) what is the difference between these two?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's the command "Preferences: Open Workspace Settings (JSON)" (`workbench.action.openWorkspaceSettingsFile`) which opens the workspace-specific settings (optionally creating the file `./.vscode/settings.json` relative to the workspace root if it doesn't exist yet). The order in which settings are overridden is as follows (from more important to less important):

1. Workspace settings
2. Global settings
3. Default settings

... i.e. if you have a certain setting in your workspace settings, it will override the same setting in your global settings; in the same manner your global settings override the defaults (and the defaults are just what VSCode ships with and what's in force if you don't change anything).

Comment: `workbench.action.openWorkspaceSettingsFile` is not a setting option

Comment: @Bn.F76 I never claimed it was a setting option; it's an invocable action that can be called through the command palette or bound to a keyboard shortcut.